# RTL resize able columns

Tags: javascript, html, css

When using RTL, the colums go crazy on resize ...

I'm using `colResizable`. Here is an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/r0rfrhb7/

```
  $("#nonFixedSample").colResizable({
  fixed: false,
  liveDrag: true,
  gripInnerHtml: "<div class='grip2'></div>",
  draggingClass: "dragging"
});
```

and the simple table code

```
<table dir="RTL" id="nonFixedSample" width="50%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <th>header</th>
    <th>header</th>
    <th>header</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="left">cellaaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td class="right">cellaaaaaaaaaa</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="left">celaaaaaaaaaaaal</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td class="right">ceaaaaaall</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="left bottom">celaaaaal</td>
    <td class="bottom">celaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaal</td>
    <td class="bottom right">celaaaaaaaal</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

what can i do ?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Open a bug on the author of the library. But they say they won't support it

http://github.com/alvaro-prieto/colResizable/issues/69

Comment: dam, do you know a way to make resize able columns like this on RTL?